# Convert ranks assigned by rank function into values

Tags: r

Sorry for the dummy question
My sample data looks like this

```
DF
    a     b       c  
    0.01  0.02   0.03
    0.08  0.09   0.10
```

I use rank to assign ranks for values in `DF` as

```
s <- sapply(DF, rank, ties.method ="average")
```

How can then i assign values to ranks? Or apparently i don't understand something.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it a data.frame or matrix?  What is your expected output?

Comment: it is a data frame. I expect data frame with values scaled according to ranks, is it possible?

Comment: Convert columns to factor and fiddle with `levels()` (or `factor()`).

Comment: Thank you. If i do like this `st <- cbind(s,as.numeric(factor(s)))` , it returns warning `number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)`, how can it be resolved? or I'm correct  at all?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand question, assuming you want ranks within column (variable)

```
> set.seed(100)
> df<-matrix(rnorm(6),ncol=3)
> df
           [,1]        [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.5021924 -0.07891709 0.1169713
[2,]  0.1315312  0.88678481 0.3186301

> s <- apply(df,2, rank, ties.method ="average")
> s
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
```

or if across all data.

```
> s <- matrix(rank(c(df), ties.method ="average"), ncol=3)
> s
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    6    5
```

Comment: But how get values assigned to ranks?

Comment: what do you mean by assign?

Comment: By `rank` command i get ranks right? but then for example how can i get the qnorm values from those ranks?

Comment: @Olga you can just do `df[s == 2]` if you want the ones with rank 2